# C# mouse events on autoclicker failing randomly

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I'm writing a small program to automate clicks on a browser game. Using the code bellow the mouse always moves to the right location, however the click on the button only works about 50% of the times. Why does it not work every time and how do i fix it?

EDIT: Here is the updated code (2 methods about image recognition left in blank due to code block size restrictions):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CICautoplayer
{

public partial class CICplayer : Form
{
    public CICplayer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwflags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    bool run = false;
    int[] corner = new int[] { 0, 0 };
    int[] pos = new int[] { 0, 0 };
    int level = 0;
    string[] logbook = new string[9] { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };

    private void runner()
    {
        while (run)
        {
            // =================================================================== identify level

            bool n1found = false;
            bool n2found = false;
            int n1 = 9;
            int n2 = 9;
            while (!n1found)
            {
                string name = "n" + n1.ToString();
                pos = new int[] { 0, 0 };
                pos = position_of_level(name, corner[0] + 0, corner[0] + 15, corner[1] + 10, corner[1] + 40);

                if (pos[0] > 0 && pos[1] > 0) { n1found = true; }
                else if (n1 > 0) { n1--; }
                else { n1found = true;}
            }
            while (!n2found)
            {
                string name = "n" + n2.ToString();
                pos = new int[] { 0, 0 };
                pos = position_of_level(name, corner[0] + 15, corner[0] + 40, corner[1] + 10, corner[1] + 40);

                if (pos[0] > 0 && pos[1] > 0){ n2found = true; }
                else if (n2 > 0) { n2--; }
                else { n2found = true;  n2 = 1000; }
            }
            level = n1 * 10 + n2;
            addentry("LVL " + level.ToString() + " => ");

            // ================================================================ target rewards

            if (level > 5)
            {
                click_on(new int[] { corner[0] + 20, corner[1] + 20 });
                Thread.Sleep(1100 + rnd.Next(1, 100));

                //string[] targetlist = new string[] { "saltpeter", "jewels", "tools", "magnificent", "steel", "bolts", "diamond", "lore"};

                string[] targetlist = new string[] { "saltpeter", "jewels", "magnificent", "bolts", "diamond", "lore" };

                int[] temp_pos = new int[] { 0, 0 };
                temp_pos = position_of("corner_slider", corner[0] + 200, corner[0] + 250, corner[1] + 250, corner[1] + 550);

                bool chosen = false;
                int n = 0;
                while (n < targetlist.Count() && !chosen)
                {
                    pos = new int[] { 0, 0 };
                    pos = position_of(targetlist[n], temp_pos[0] + 200, temp_pos[0] + 550, temp_pos[1], temp_pos[1] + 50);
                    if (pos[0] != 0 && pos[1] != 0)
                    {
                        click_on(new int[] { pos[0] + 10, pos[1] + 10 });
                        chosen = true;
                    }
                    n++;
                }

                if (chosen)
                {
                    addentry("Rwrd: " + targetlist[n - 1] + " => ");
                }
                else
                {
                    addentry("Rwrd: NONE! => ");
                }


                // fecher o menu das rewards
                Thread.Sleep(1000 + rnd.Next(1, 100));
                click_on(new int[] { corner[0] + 50, corner[1] + 400 });
            }

            // =============================================================== wait time

            int wtime = 0;
            if (level < 30) { wtime = 4000 + level * 200;
            } else if (level < 60)
            {
                wtime = 10000 + level * 250;
            } else
            {
                wtime = 25000;
            }

            addentry("Wait: " + (wtime/1000).ToString() + " sec => ");
            Thread.Sleep(wtime);

            // ================================================================ reset
            if (run) // condition in case the stop button is pressed meanwhile
            {
                addentry("reseting... \r\n");
                click_on(new int[] { corner[0] + 20, corner[1] + 20 });
                Thread.Sleep(2000 + rnd.Next(1, 500));

                // select restart
                int[] p_but = new int[] { 0, 0 };
                p_but = position_of("button_restart", corner[0] + 450, corner[0] + 550, corner[1] + 200, corner[1] + 400);
                p_but[0] += 10; p_but[1] += 10;
                click_on(p_but);

                Thread.Sleep(4000 + rnd.Next(1, 500));

                click_on(new int[] { corner[0] + 700, corner[1] + (level < 6 ? 335 : 385)});
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

        }

    }

    public void click_on(int[] coor)
    {
        SetCursorPos(coor[0], coor[1]);
        Application.DoEvents();
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, coor[0], coor[1], 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, coor[0], coor[1], 0, 0);
    }

    private void addentry(string text)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(addentry), new object[] { text });
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { logbook[i] = logbook[i + 1]; }
        logbook[8] = text;

        logtext.Text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            logtext.Text += logbook[i];
        }
    }

    private int[] position_of(string what, int xmin, int xmax, int ymin, int ymax)
    {
        // code to identify a picture in a specified area of the screen
        // returns int[2] with the coordinates
    }

    private int[] position_of_level(string what, int xmin, int xmax, int ymin, int ymax)
    {
        // code to identify a number in a specified area of the screen
        // returns int[2] with the coordinates
    }

    private void but_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        corner = position_of("corner", 0, 500, 0, 600);
        addentry("Corner found at " + corner[0].ToString() + " , " + corner[1].ToString() + "\r\n");
        run = true;
        var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(runner));
        thread.Start();
    }
    private void but_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        run = false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why is `private void runner() {}` empty

Comment: @AleksaRistic I omitted the content on the question because I don't think is related to the problem, runner is the method that calls `click_on`

Comment: Could you please post it since i think problem lays there

Comment: Updated. The editor put a restriction on code size so I emptied the content of the image recognition methods, the rest is all there